# Circular Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

Context: Create a circular, doubly linked list from a file (input.txt), containing a list of names. The number of names is unknown.

Prompt the user for the number of nodes to delete and then delete accordingly from the list.

Assumption: The number inputted by the user will not exceed the actual number of nodes in the list.

Question: My delete node function is not working, as when I go to display what is in the node that was supposedly deleted, the data is still there. Any Help?

My code: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/210015/

(I am linking to this other website because it was easier to format there.)

Comment: The code should be included here. Format it using a editor and then copy/paste it here.

Comment: And possibly, don't force us to rely on an input file to feed the compilerd code.

Comment: And before the copy/paste, reduce the code into a [mcve], and verify that it reproduces the problem.

Comment: [tutorial here](http://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q)

Answer (score 2):

> My delete node function is not working, as when I go to display what is in the node that was supposedly deleted, the data is still there.

Accessing a destroyed (deleted) object has undefined behaviour.

You cannot *expect* how the program behaves when the behaviour is undefined. Therefore your *expectation* that *"data shouldn't be there"* was ill-founded. A correct expectation is that data might, or might not be there, and that the program might or might not crash and that daemons might or might not fly out of the users nose.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for `void deleteNode(struct node *&head)` has a lot of bugs.

1. you don't check if `head` is nullptr
2. you don't check if `current->next` and/or `current->prev` are nullptr

accessing nullptr pointers is undefined behaviour, that may mean a crash or unexpected results  or whatever.

Comment: `current->next` and `current->prev` are never nullptr.

Comment: That should be, IIF the linkedlist insert is corretly implemented. But, based on the deleteNode() I would play safely and at least putting some assert() here and there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using following delete function to delete the node.
Note: assuming delete starts from the head.

```
  void deleteNode(struct node *&head,int deleteCount)
  {
        if(head != NULL){
            struct node *current=head; //copy of head.
            struct node *temp,*headPrev,*headNext;
            headPrev = head->prev;
            headNext = head->next;
            int count = 0;
            while(count++ < deleteCount)   
            {
                 //add code to free current node from me
                 temp = current; //get rid of this node
                 currrent = current->next; //skip all the nodes you want delete
            }
            current->prev = headPrev;
            headPrev->next = current;
            head = current;
        }
  }
```

Comment: two points: it is circular doubly linked list, so there won't be a null pointer and number of delete nodes are always less than total number of nodes

Comment: How many nodes are you delete-ing?

Comment: I am following this  Assumption: The number inputted by the user will not exceed the actual number of nodes in the list.

Comment: Let put it in this way: assume deleteCount > 1, how many nodes are you really destroying (delete called on them)? And how many are you leaking?
BTW, your code better check for your assumptions ;-)

Comment: okay, I am just removing all the node from the list. we need to free the memory for that nodes as well. not much familiar with c++

Comment: "you need to free the memory"... "you" cannot do that, if you don't have anymore the pointers to the other nodes, that's what memory leak is. Your code is just plain wrong.